# Clarification on proof by contradiction in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let's say that I have a finite directed graph. Also assume that every vertex in the graph has *only one unique* closest neighbor. How can I prove that the maximum length of any cycle in this graph is 2? I read a proof online but I don't really get it, I'll paste it here:

Let us denote by d(u, v) the distance between vertices u and v. Consider any three consecutive
vertices u, v, and w on a cycle. If u and w are distinct, then the existence of the edge from v to w
implies that d(v, w) < d(v, u). Since d(v, u) = d(u, v) and any three consecutive points on a cycle of length more than 2 are distinct, this means that the distance of two consecutive points on a cycle
of length 3 strictly decreases as we go around the cycle. However, the latter is impossible because
the graph is ﬁnite, so at some point we will reach the same pair (u, v) as we started from, so we’d
obtain the contradiction that d(u, v) < d(u, v).

The parts I don't understand are why d(v,u) = d(u,v) and how they reached the contradiction. could someone explain in some more detail please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a finite set $V$ of vertices, and for each pair of distinct vertices a positive real distance between them. This distance function is symmetric: for any vertices $u$ and $v$, the distance from $u$ to $v$, written $d(u,v)$, is the same as the distance from $v$ to $u$, written $d(v,u)$. (It is sometimes further assumed that $d$ is a genuine metric: $d(u,v)\ge 0$, with equality iff $u=v$, and $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality, but all that’s needed for the present result is symmetry.) We further assume that no two pairs have the same associated distance.

We now add directed edges to make this a directed graph in the following way: for each vertex $u$ we find the unique vertex $v$ closest to $u$ and draw an edge from $u$ to $v$. This means that each vertex has outdegree $1$: there is only one edge going out from it, and that edge goes to the nearest other vertex.

Now suppose that $u,v$, and $w$ are consecutive vertices on a cycle, and that $u\ne w$. Then we have edges $u\longrightarrow v\longrightarrow w$. Since the only edge out of $v$ goes to $u$, $u$ is closer to $v$ than any other vertex; in particular, $d(v,w)<d(v,u)$. As noted above, the distance function is symmetric, so $d(v,u)=d(u,v)$, and therefore $d(v,w)<d(u,v)$. Suppose, now, that we have a cycle $u_1u_2\ldots u_nu_1$, where $n\ge 3$. The argument just given, applied to the point $u_1,u_2$, and $u_3$, shows that $d(u_1,u_2)>d(u_2,u_3)$. The same argument applied to $u_2,u_3$, and $u_4$ shows that $d(u_2,u_3)>d(u_3,u_4)$. In fact, if $1\le k\le n-2$, it shows that $d(u_k,u_{k+1})>d(u_{k+1},u_{k+2})$. Thus, the lengths of the ‘steps’ on the path

$$u_1\longrightarrow u_2\longrightarrow u_3\longrightarrow\ldots\longrightarrow u_n$$

are strictly decreasing, and in particular $d(u_{n-1},u_n)$, the length of the last step, is less than $d(u_1,u_2)$, the length of the first step. Now we apply the result to the vertices $u_{n-1},u_n$, and $u_1$, which are also consecutive on the cycle, finding that $d(u_{n-1},u_n)>d(u_n,u_1)$, and to $u_n,u_1$, and $u-2$, finding that $d(u_n,u_1)>d(u_1,u_2)$. We now have the inequality

$$d(u_1,u_2)>d(u_{n-1},u_n)>d(u_n,u_1)>d(u_1,u_2)\;,$$

which is clearly impossible. Thus, there can be no cycle of length greater than $2$.